# Computing the integral using cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I need to integrate

$$\oint _{|z|=1} \frac {\sin z}{z}\, dz$$

I write $\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-...$, then I get by dividing by $x$, the series $1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-...$. I am confused as to how to use this to integrate. What happens to $\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-...$ now?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is on the real line then you are just integrating at -1 and 1, so the integral is zero. I assume this is a complex integral? If so, it's more customary to use $z$ than $x$.

Comment: yes I know I changed it to $x$ because that feels better. But you are right

Comment: By Cauchy's integral theorem wouldn't the integral be zero because the function is analytic in the region which the coutour belongs to?

Comment: If the integration contour is $|z|=1$, then the value is zero since $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is analytic (with the removable discontinuity at $z=0$).

Comment: @okrzysik it depends what you mean.  For example, $1/z$ is analytic in an open neighborhood of the contour.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I mean that the function $f(z) = \sin(z)/z$ is analytic everywhere inside and on the unit disk which is enclosed by the integration contour $|z| = 1$. So by the integral theorem the integral of $f(z)$ around $|z|=1$ has to be zero.

Answer (score 4):

We manage write the function $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ as a power series
$$
F(z) = 1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-...,
$$
which converges in $\mathbb C$. That means $F(z)$ is analytic and by Cauchy's theorem
$$
\oint_{|z|=1}F(z)\, dz = 0.
$$

---

To be more formal note that $\frac{\sin z}{z} = F(z)$ when $z\in\mathbb C\setminus 0$, and, in particular when $|z|=1$. So 
$$
\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin z}{z}\, dz = \oint_{|z|=1}F(z)\, dz = 0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(z)=sin(z)$ is entire. In particular, it is analytic on the unit disk. By [Cauchy's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), we have 
$$
f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\|z\|=1}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}dz
$$
for any $z_0$ in the interior of the unit disk. Now apply this for a suitable choice of $z_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$, and that the function
$$
f(z) = \begin{cases}
\sin z & z \neq 0 \\
1 & z = 0
\end{cases}
$$
is entire (that is, $\sin z/z$ has a *removable discontinuity* at $z = 0$).  Because $f$ is entire, we have
$$
\oint \frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz = \oint f(z)\,dz = 0
$$